# In Spring boot, When the new document is created when using @Document annotation?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am new to spring and MongoDB. So, hear is the use case I want to understand.

In SpringBoot and MongoDB structure. I am trying to insert a new document in Mongo, hence used @Document in Java POJO/Domain/Data class. Now, I have written my code and starting the server. My question is, when the collection will be created in MongoDB? i.e. while starting the server (Spring will scan all the classes with @Document and create collection id DB while creating classes) or when the repository code is invoked (when I am trying to perform any CRUD operations)?

Comment: The latter option. Your first option makes no sense. The annotation is at a class level, but you would need to persist instances.

Comment: ok thanks for the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

The collection in MongoDB along with indexes is created when the repository code is invoked to perform CRUD operations ..